# Are high-s ECDSA signatures forbidden in segwit witnesses?

Tags: segregated-witness, signature, ecdsa

I must have looked that up five times by now, but did segwit actually forbid high-s ECDSA signatures in witnesses, esp. in standard single-sig constructions such as P2SH-P2WPKH or P2WPKH? Or are high-s signatures still only non-standard even in segwit inputs?

<sub>(I'm aware that the transaction malleability problem due to low-s/high-s is mitigated by moving the signature into the witness, that's not my question.)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are still just non-standard.